# UILocalNotification are showing only on lock screen/Notification screen

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Whenever app receive silent push , I am displaying the local notification. 
If at the time of receiving the silent push , iPhone is locked , local notification are displaying but if application is in background and iPhone is not locked then local notification are not displaying. What could be wrong. ? I am using below code ?

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Connect"
content.body = indentificationText
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1,
                                                repeats: false)

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = appDelegate
content.userInfo = payload.dictionaryPayload


let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: content.title, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
    NSLog("UNUserNotificationCenter Add completion Handler : \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The app may be suspended in the *background* , so the code that creates the *local notification* isn't executed . . .